# Onload Binding using knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, binding, knockout.js

I Want to execute a function when the page load but don't know how to do it. cause that I have a list but his data from to another place in the load.

Comment: are you using jquery as well on your page?

Comment: not am not using jquery on my page it's just simple javascript

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are refreshing page content through an AJAX call and you want to make that AJAX call on the page load in ADDITION to binding it to an event.

Assuming that is the case, at the end of your ModelViewModel declaration, simply call the function. For example:

```
function SearchResultsViewModel(){
    this.updateResults=function(){
      //Some AJAX Call and action.   
    }
    this.updateResults();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You bind the knockout viewmodel to the view as normal, then use

```
window.onload = function ()
{
     //data from to another place in the load
}
```

or in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //data from to another place in the load
)};
```

Since knockout is bound to the view, when you add items, the view will update automatically.

Comment: when I do this cause me an error I don't know why this

    model = new model();
    ko.applyBindings(model);

but this way work perfectly
    ko.applyBindings(new model())

Comment: Can you edit this jsfiddle to match the issue you are having? This will help me help you http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmore/wVdnL/

Comment: how can that help me is another topic :S